# Collect2.exe error: ld returned 5 exit status

Tags: c, operating-system, mingw, ld

I am creating an Operating System with BootLoader and Kernel and a Linker. I want to compile these three and make them 1 file, but it gives me an unexplainable error. EX. I have boot.asm and compiled it to boot.o. but I compile boot.o, kmain.cpp, linker.ld, it gives me the error

This is my boot.asm:

```
section .boot
bits 16
global boot
boot:
    mov ax, 0x2401
    int 0x15

    mov ax, 0x3
    int 0x10

    mov [disk],dl

    mov ah, 0x2    ;read sectors
    mov al, 6      ;sectors to read
    mov ch, 0      ;cylinder idx
    mov dh, 0      ;head idx
    mov cl, 2      ;sector idx
    mov dl, [disk] ;disk idx
    mov bx, copy_target;target pointer
    int 0x13
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_pointer]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax,0x1
    mov cr0, eax
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    jmp CODE_SEG:boot2
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0
gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:
gdt_pointer:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start
    dd gdt_start
disk:
    db 0x0
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
copy_target:
bits 32
    hello: db "Booting system...",0
boot2:
    mov esi,hello
    mov ebx,0xb8000
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al,al
    jz halt
    or eax,0x0F00
    mov word [ebx], ax
    add ebx,2
    jmp .loop
halt:
    mov esp,kernel_stack_top
    extern kmain
    call kmain
    cli
    hlt

section .bss
align 4
kernel_stack_bottom: equ $
    resb 16384 ; 16 KB
kernel_stack_top:
```

And my kmain.cpp:

```
extern "C" void kmain()
{
    const short color = 0x0F00;
    const char* hello = "Welcome to my third version of my first operating system but with C++!!";
    short* vga = (short*)0xb8000;
    for (int i = 0; i<16;++i)
        vga[i+80] = color | hello[i];
}
```

And finally my linker.ld:

```
ENTRY(boot)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x7c00;
    .text :
    {
        *(.boot)
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

I just want it to compile these. I have been finding all over the internet. but no useful things. Please answer as fast as possible. Thank you!!

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status

Comment: Not this one. There's more output.

Comment: This is the only thing i get. but i did -verbose and i got this: https://pastebin.com/raw/bzPbKfyj

Comment: You need to look for error messages displayed by ld itself.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to do this command line: g++ x86_64-elf-g++ -m64 kmain.cpp boot.o -o kernel.bin -nostdlib -ffreestanding -std=c++11 -mno-red-zone -fno-exceptions -nostdlib -fno-rtti -Wall -Wextra -Werror -T linker.ld --verbose                                  , and collect2.exe gives me an error that ld.exe exited (crashed) with status 5

Comment: Nothing else. I wanna know what this code (5) means

Comment: The exit status is just what `ld` returned from it's `main` function (or was used as an argument to `exit`). The codes appear to be undocumented, so who knows in what cases you get 5. You would have to dig into the `ld` source. Even then you likely won't find information specific enough to help you to get it to compile correctly.